# Dificuldade com alocação dinâmica de struct

Tags: c, struct, alocação

A questão é : 
implementar um tipo de dado TBaralho para representar uma pilha de cartas.
Seu tipo de dados deverá armazenar as cartas do baralho e a quantidade de cartas presente. Considere
que o tamanho máximo de um baralho é limitado pela memória principal (você deverá usar alocação
dinâmica) e deve crescer de 10 em 10 elementos (consulte a função em C realloc1, não será permitido
o uso de encadeamento). Use arranjos unidimensionais (vetores) para implementar o TAD.

Eu consigo alocar dinamicante uma struct dentro de outra struct ?

```
typedef struct carta{
    char naip;
    int num;
} TCarta;

typedef struct baralho{
    TCarta *vet_carta;
    int qtd_carta;
} TBaralho; //baralho

void inicializar (TBaralho *pBaralho)
{
    pBaralho = (TBaralho*) malloc(10*sizeof(TBaralho));
    pBaralho->qtd_carta=0;
}
```

Comment: Sim, da mesma forma como fez para pBaralho. Por ex.: pCarta = (TCarta*) malloc(10*sizeof(TCarta)); ou ainda pBaralho[i].vet_carta = (TCarta*) malloc(10*sizeof(TCarta));

Comment: A dica foi muito boa, enquanto eu mandei esse post eu fui testando e conseguindo.

Comment: ```
if (pBaralho->qtd_carta==52 && pBaralho->vet_carta[pos]=NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```
Como eu testo se um vetor de struct na posição X esta vazio ? Dessa forma que eu coloquei nao deu certo =/